# How to send ScrollNotification to parent Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to animate the bottom navigation to hide or show when the user scrolls. I was able to achieve this when the bottom navigation bar is in the same Scaffold in which the NotificationListener() is ([dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/280e5e38423ba46fdc6e6b9903b8854f?)).

But now that the complexity of my app increased, I had to make separate navigators for each tab and a holding scaffold that has a bottom navigation bar, following [this](https://edsonbueno.com/2020/01/23/bottom-navigation-in-flutter-mastery-guide/) post.

Here's the simplified version ([dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/2b11b48642e0af673beafdc47baab87f?)):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(ScrollExample());

class ScrollExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AnimatedPositioned Demo',
      home: DashBoard(),
    );
  }
}

class TabNavigator {
  const TabNavigator({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.iconData,
    @required this.key,
  })  : assert(title != null),
        assert(iconData != null),
        assert(key != null);

  final String title;
  final IconData iconData;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key;
}

/// Page that displays its index, flow's title and color.
///
/// Has a button for pushing another one of its kind with an incremented index,
/// and another button for starting a new flow named 'New' with
/// a random background color.
abstract class IndexedView extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext parentContext;

  const IndexedView({
    Key key,
    this.parentContext,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// Handles the navigation for each tab.
  void pushPage(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool isHorizontalNavigation,
  });
}

class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  AnimationController _hide;

  final _tabs = <TabNavigator>[
    TabNavigator(
        key: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
        title: 'Sales',
        iconData: Icons.ac_unit),
    TabNavigator(
        key: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
        title: 'Settings',
        iconData: Icons.settings),
  ];

  bool _handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification.depth == 0) {
      if (notification is UserScrollNotification) {
        final UserScrollNotification userScroll = notification;
        switch (userScroll.direction) {
          case ScrollDirection.forward:
            _hide.forward();
            break;
          case ScrollDirection.reverse:
            _hide.reverse();
            break;
          case ScrollDirection.idle:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _hide = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: kThemeAnimationDuration);
    _hide.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _hide.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentFlow = _tabs[_selectedTab];

    // We're preventing the root navigator from popping and closing the app
    // when the back button is pressed and the inner navigator can handle it.
    // That occurs when the inner has more than one page on its stack.
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => !await currentFlow.key.currentState.maybePop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedTab,
          children: _tabs
              .map(
                (tab) => _buildIndexedViewFlow(tab, context),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: _hide,
          axisAlignment: -1.0,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedTab,
            items: _tabs
                .map(
                  (flow) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    label: flow.title,
                    icon: Icon(flow.iconData),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onTap: (newIndex) => setState(
              () {
                if (_selectedTab != newIndex) {
                  _selectedTab = newIndex;
                } else {
                  // If the user is re-selecting the tab, the common
                  // behavior is to empty the stack.
                  currentFlow.key.currentState
                      .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                }
              },
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIndexedViewFlow(TabNavigator tab, BuildContext parentContext) =>
      Navigator(
        // The key enables us to access the Navigator's state inside the
        // onWillPop callback and for emptying its stack when a tab is
        // re-selected. That is why a GlobalKey is needed instead of
        // a simpler ValueKey.
        key: tab.key,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => _generateRoute(tab.title, parentContext),
      );

  MaterialPageRoute<IndexedView> _generateRoute(
    String title,
    BuildContext parentContext,
  ) {
    final sales = Sales();
    final settings = Sales();

    switch (title) {
      case 'SalesViewRoute':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => sales);
      case 'SettingsViewRoute':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => settings);

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => sales);
    }
  }
}

class Sales extends IndexedView {
  final BuildContext parentContext;

  Sales({this.parentContext}) : super(parentContext: parentContext);

  @override
  _SalesState createState() => _SalesState();

  @override
  void pushPage(BuildContext context,
      {bool isHorizontalNavigation, String routeName}) {}
}

class _SalesState extends State<Sales> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        // How to send notification to Dashboard ??
        onNotification: (_) {
          print('scrolling');
          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Sroll it!'),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (_, __) => FlutterLogo(),
            itemCount: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just to wrap the IndexedStack widget (in parent Scaffold) with NotificationListener and everything works as intended.

```dart
      Scaffold(
        body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (_) {
          _handleScrollNotification(_);
          return false;
        }, child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedTab,
          children: _tabs
              .map(
                (tab) => _buildIndexedViewFlow(tab, context),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),),
```